# Stored Procedure output to file truncated

Tags: sql-server, cmd, sqlcmd

I have a stored procedure in my local SQL Server that has one line output, line is about 1500 characters long. When I execute that stored procedure from `sqlcmd` (both PowerShell and CMD) the line gets cut off after 255 characters.

Here's the `sqlcmd` statement:

```
sqlcmd -S (local)\sqlexpress -E -d ReleaseTeam -Q "exit(exec[dbo].[SP_LOG_GETEMAILBODYHTML_TODAY])" -h-1 -o "D:\path\index.html"
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I would look at the `-y` and `-Y` [switches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

Comment: I guess the issue is in your datatype, please make sure the datatype's length is set to MAX instead of 255

Comment: @MCND, thanks. Adding -y 8000 solved the issue.